# Is there a Machine Learning Frame in R rather than caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, references

I was using caret for years.

I was wondering if there is a similar ML framework like caret.

Like in python they have several systems in deep learning (keras, pytorch, tensorflow, etc).

Just want to open my mind and to see a bigger world.

Any books or links will be fine, I could read my self. And a detailed answer is also welcomed, but if you don't have time, throw me a link or book well be appreciated.

Comment: A quick search of packages on CRAN suggests https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/keras/ and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/torch/ and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tensorflow exist, though I have never used them

Comment: @Henry thank you very much, I will explore them recently